# Access VBA open form on current record

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form in loading records in continuous mode that looks like a datasheet. I want to have a button at the beginning of each row of data that I can click on the will open up a form for users to edit.

So far I got the edit form to load by using
    DoCmd.OpenForm

This loads the first record no matter which record's button I click on. I tried the 
    DoCmd.Gotorecord
and this does not work. How can I fix this>?

Answer (score 2):

DoCmd.OpenForm "YourFormName", acNormal, , "YourUniqueID=" & Me!YourUniqueID